# how to solve this formula limits's formula

Tags: calculus, limits

I have already known one way to solve this formula but I just want to know the easier way to do so: $$\lim_{ u \to 0} \frac{\sin(u)}{u}=1$$

Please kindly help me!! Thank You.

Comment: It would help if you explain your way.

Comment: You haven't defined what u is. Do you mean as $u \to 0$?

Comment: "the" easier way? Easier than what?

Comment: Easier that what?

Comment: See also: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Sine_of_X_over_X

Answer (score 0):

Using L'hopital's rule,

$$\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{\sin u}{u} = \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{du}\sin u}{\frac{d}{du}u} = \lim_{u \to 0} \cos u = 1$$

Comment: Sir my country doesn't study this equation in high school so I don't know what it is

Comment: Can u pls solve another way ? What is l'hospital's

Comment: @John, this proof is circular. Have a look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13008/why-are-people-so-interested-in-finding-limits-without-lh%C3%B4pitals-rule/13011#13011).

Comment: @k170, thanks. Very interesting post!

Comment: @MangSopheak, please see the other previous posts of this question as this question is a duplicate.